# Push notifications with minimal data usage

Tags: python, web, push-notification, connection, network-protocols

In my project, I want to call an action on a Raspberry Pi from the Internet. Somehow like that:

1. Visit webpage
2. Hit a button on the webpage
3. Raspberry pi executes a script

The difficult part is, that the raspberry pi only has a mobile Internet connection *without a flatrate*. So, sending and receiving data from/to the Raspberry Pi is costly.

So this is my question:

Which technologies and patterns can I use to send push notifications to the raspberry pi *with minimal data usage*?

Comment: `Pi opens a listening socket -> Pi connects to HTTP -> servers saves IP -> when server has something -> connect to last known IP on port X -> send data -> close connection` done?

Comment: wouldn't the open socket permanently use data? Sorry for my lack of knowledge in this thing - do you have a link where I can read about that?

Comment: Not unless you send data. Or if you set the session timeout to short. Or you go with UDP.

Comment: Correction, a listening Socket on the pi never uses data unless you connect. Answered on the phone a bit to quick.

Comment: Ok. One more question: would the pi notify the server if it gets a new ip address?

Comment: You would simply have a daemon on your pi that checks for IP changes and do a new connect whenever that happens

Comment: Sounds good. If you want to make an answer out of that, I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start off by creating or starting something that accepts incoming connections on your RPi. Something small as the below example would do:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from socket import *
s = socket()
s.bind(('', 8001))
s.listen(4)
while 1:
    ns, na = s.accept()
    print(na,'sent you:',ns.recv(8192))
```

Now, the above example will only open a port on `8001` and then print whatever the other send sent to it.

On the server end, I suggest you setup a web server or something else that is easily accessible that can store an IP in a database/register somewhere.

Then, during boot of your RPi (pref after the networking service is started) go ahead and schedule:

```
curl https://your-server.eu/reg_ip.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Now, on the server `your-server.eu:443`, make sure `req_ip.php` saves the clients IP (client being your RPi) in a database somewhere.

Now, which ever application that you have that need to send out PUSH notifications can lookup the current IP of clients in the database and try to connect to port `8001` on those IP's and send whatever data you need.

Now two things:

1. A listening TCP socket (on the RPi) won't use up any data at all but will allow for incomming connections when needed.
2. If your IP changes on the RPi (which it probably will on a moving GSM/3G/4G network for instance), you need to do another `curl` request to your server. This however could easily be tied to a for instance `ip monitor` command and perform the curl request then.

## tl;dr

Here's your chain:

`Pi opens a listening socket -> Pi connects to HTTP(S) -> servers saves IP -> when server has something to send -> connect to last known IP on port X -> send data -> close connection`

## Enhancing further

Now, the HTTP header alone is quite big, in fact it's default 78 bytes of package data (TCP and IP headers usually isn't included in data rates, only the data being transferred is - in this case, HTTP data.). So what you could expand on is if you could use the simple example of a socket above on the server as well and just take the `na[0]` variable and send that to a database, that way you use literally 0 data-rate on your data subscription.

Only the actual data sent then later on from the server application as a "PUSH notification" would use up data.

## In case your RPi is on a NAT based network (private network)

Seeing as the OP gets a `10.X.X.X` address it's unlikely that a listening socket will do the trick.

Instead, what you could do is you could simply try and establish a connection and keep it open and have the server send data over any open socket when it has data.

Here's an extremely rough idea of how you could achieve it.
I kept it simple and stupid just to give an idea without solving the entire thing.

Again, the open socket between the client (RPi) and the Server won't use up any data until you actually send data over the channel.

You could in your server fetch data from a database that you want to send to the clients, you could do anything really. Since I don't know your goal I'll just leave it as it is for the time being.

### Server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from socket import *
from threading import *
from time import time, sleep
from random import randint

class ClientThread(Thread)
    def __init__(self, clients):
        self.clients = clients
        self.messages = []
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def notify(self, message):
        if type(message) is str: message = bytes(message, 'UTF-8')
        self.messages.append(message)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            if len(self.messages) > 0:
                m = self.messages.pop(0)
                for client in self.clients:
                    self.clients[client]['sock'].send(m)

class RandomMessageGenerator(Thread):
    def __init__(self, notify_func):
        self.notify_func = notify_func
        self.last = time()
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            self.notify_func('Time since last update: ' + str(time() - self.last))
            self.last = time()
            sleep(randint(0,30))

client_list = {}
client_thread_handle = ClientThread(client_list)
random_generator = RandomMessageGenerator(client_thread_handle.nofity)

s = socket()
s.bind(('', 8001))
s.listen(4)

while 1:
    ns, na = s.accept()
    client_list[na] = {'sock' : 'ns'}
```

### Client:

```
from socket import *
s = socket()
s.connect(('server', 8001))
while 1:
    print(s.recv(8192))
```

Comment: With the help of a friend, I did some more research and realized, there is at least one major problem: my mobile devices would not receive an external IP when they are connected over GSM/UMTS/LTE/etc. See this screenshot from my phone: https://owncloud.yeara.net/s/80jJkEuUOW2sjAh

Comment: @speendo Isn't `213.147.163.39` your external IP?

Comment: Thanks for checking! I could be wrong, but as far as I understand that, this is the IP adress of the next GSM antenna.

Comment: @speendo I still think that IP would be your phones actual external IP and it should be accessible from any given host as long as you open a socket. The rest should be virtual interfaces that your phone sets up (not knowing your OS, version etc.. so this is a guess). However i included another longer answer for the cases where you're behind a NAT situation. Hopefully that helps some what, kinda basic but should do the trick

Comment: you are awesome! I will give both options a try!

Comment: @speendo Pleasure is all mine. I hope it works out. Been using something similar on a RPi in my car where data coverage is limited. Be sure to integrate a lot of error handling and stuff!